# Saving Canvas as blob and then blob as file

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, blob

This is more or less an icon on the page that when clicked does something, but the icon on the page is currently an anchor.  I can change this to a div (all the rest of the icons are divs for that matter in my UI), but for some reason the following doesn't work.

Why does the first click register nothing?

```js
$('#a').click(save);

function save(ev) {
  $('#canvas')[0].toBlob((blob) => {
    let URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    ev.target.href = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob)
    ev.target.download = "untitled.png";
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
<a id='a'>click me to save</a>
```

Fiddle to see behavior:
https://jsfiddle.net/udbq3fb7/

Comment: If you inspect the element in your browser, you'll see it starts off without an href attribute (or just look at how you defined the source).  After you click it the first time, you are setting the href on it.  It then knows where to go for the second click.

Comment: jquery is in my code.  look at the fiddle it is already referencing it.  I didn't update the question with the code snippet, you did, which the snippet doesn't allow library additions.

Comment: Including the logic to reproduce the issue on site, rather than only linking to an external paste service, is preferred.

Comment: When the asynchronous `toBlob`'s callback fires, your click event is long time dead. The default behavior will have been executed already, and simply overriding your `<a>` href's would have no direct effect. You would have to trigger yourself your `<a>`'s `click()` method, but it will create an infinite loop of `save`... So better use an new anchor, or even better, a [library](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) that would even handle quirks.

Comment: Thanks Kaiido I'll get back to you on trying to create a new element inside the callback.

Comment: Can't figure this out sorry @Kaiido

Comment: Why is the event dead when its specified in the function header where the code is running?

Comment: A better question perhaps:  Is there a way to maintain the state of the event into that callback?  That would also solve my problem.

Comment: using FileSaver works for me as a solution, just tested and verified, so thank you @Kaiido

Comment: @simon if you got your solution, you can post an answer to your question and then mark it as answered. It might help other people.

Comment: @theAlexandrian I figured another solution after much trial and effort without using a lib as well.  Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through much trial and effort, without using a 3rd party, here is an answer that works too:

```
$('#a').click(save);

function save(ev) {
   $('#canvas')[0].toBlob((blob) => {
        let URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        let a = document.createElement("a");  
        a.href = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = "untitled.png";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
   });
}
```

fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/rkqkr47w/

Comment: it looks like this causes the blob to leak, because `revokeObjectUrl()` is not called? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209756/do-i-always-need-to-call-url-revokeobjecturl-explicitly and https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#url-intro

Comment: Probably not as in this case the anchor is being removed from the DOM I would assume.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a walk-through the current situation:

1. User clicks.
2. Event gets dispatched in the document.
3. EventHandlers fire [if any].
4. default click behavior happens [if not prevented in 3.].

Now, what your code is trying to do is to overwrite the default behavior of the click (4.) action, by changing your `<a>`'s `href` in the event handlers (3.).

This trick normally works, because 3. happens before 4., but in your case, you are calling an *asynchronous* method in 3., and the `href` is only changed after your async callback gets called.

So you have

...
3. Canvas.toBlob(callback)
4. default click behavior happens
...
n. callback fires (change default behavior)

When your callback gets called, your click event is long dead, and changing its `href` will have incidence only on the **next** click.

---

You could call directly the `<a>`'s `click` method inside this callback, but it would lead to an infinite loop, except if you remove the event handler and reassign it again, but it would probably be easier to create a new `<a>` element altogether, that you would remove afterward, and even easier to use a library like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) which does exactly this along with handling some quirks in older browsers.

```js
$('#a').click(save);

function save(ev) {
  $('#canvas')[0].toBlob((blob) => {
    saveAs(blob, "untitled.png");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
<a id='a'>click me to save</a>
```

Comment: accepted as answer.

this all stemmed from the fact that some of the canvas data generated from my first call using toDataURL() was too big to fit into the anchor itself.